# Conversion failed when converting the nvarchar value to data type int during mass insert

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a simple example database table called `test`, where the column `name` is a `nvarchar`, and the column `value` is a `decimal,9,2`

I'm trying to understand why the following SQL statement fails:

```
insert into [test] ([name], [value]) values ('test1', '33.9'), ('test2', 33)
```

This gives an error of

> [22018] [Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 10.0][SQL Server]Conversion failed when converting the varchar value '33.9' to data type int. (245)

In this scenario, because one of the values `33.9` was listed as a `string`, MSSQL tries to convert all of them to an `int`?

**Some other examples that do work:**

This works when both values are `numeric`:

```
insert into [test] ([name], [value]) values ('test1', 33.9), ('test2', 33)
```

and this works when both values are `string`:

```
insert into [test] ([name], [value]) values ('test1', '33.9'), ('test2', '33')
```

it also works when one value is a `string` and one is a `numeric` if they easily cast to int:

```
insert into [test] ([name], [value]) values ('test1', '33'), ('test2', 33)
```

it also works if you insert them one at a time:

```
insert into [test] ([name], [value]) values ('test1', '33.9')
insert into [test] ([name], [value]) values ('test1', 33)
```

**Application:**

Now - the easy answer is "just use the same data type". The way we detected this error was during mass inserts, where data is taken from an application and inserted.

It seems strange to only fail in this one specific way, when it will quite happily handle all of the other scenarios, including inserting one at a time.

Is there a way to disable this behavior? Or an explanation of why it occurs at all? This does not occur in mySQL, <s>Postgres etc</s> - they all work.

**"Why does your VALUES clause have inconsistent types? The problem (apart from the string), is that the types are inconsistent"**

In this scenario, we were storing GPS values (which are floats). By chance, the returned GPS output went from -33.001 to -33 as the vehicle was moving (i.e. an "exact" GPS output of an integer).

Comment: That because SQL Server has a [Data type precedence](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/data-type-precedence-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)

Comment: The clear application bug is using **strings** instead of numeric values. How those *strings* are *parsed* depends on the server's locale. If MySQL or PostgreSQL work with this it's purely by a localization accident

Comment: SQL Server try to convert the string to INT because of `('test2', 33)` 33 is INT and INT has high precedence than N/VARCHAR

Comment: Why does your `VALUES` clause have inconsistent types? The problem (apart from the string), is that the types are inconsistent. In a `VALUES` clause all the columns will be defined as a datatype, and implicitly converted based on data type precedence. For your second col;umn in the `VALUES` clause you have the `int` `33` and the `varchar(4)` `'33.9'`. `int` has a higher precedence than `varchar`, and so the `varchar` is converted; and hence the error. Provide your data as the correct data type and this problem goes away. This isn't a SQL Server error, it's an input error.

Comment: BTW no repro with actual *numbers*. The problem is mixing up numbers and strings

Comment: Something tells me your data is not what you expect it to be. What if the two values were accidentally swapped or typed in incorrectly in one row in your entire batch of millions of rows?

Comment: PostgreSQL *doesn't* accept that input either. It fails with `ERROR: invalid input syntax for integer: "33.9"`.

Comment: So the answer to `Why it occurs at all?` is this is MySQL-specific behavior which doesn't work in other databases.

Comment: @Larnu - I've editted my original question with how this scenario occurred. A GPS tracking system had a moment where the vehicle was *exactly* at -33 latitude, instead of -33.001 etc. So we had the system return an integer unexpectedly.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos - sorry, I've edited my question and removed PostGres. It definitely works with mySQL.

Comment: That doesn't change the actual problem @Laurence. If you had the values `33` and `33.9` then the `33` would be implicitly converted to a `decimal(3,1)`. The problem is that you didn't supply a `decimal` you supplied a `varchar`. Don't supply the numerical data as a string and the problem solves itself. it's not the `int`'s fault, it's the `varchar`'s.

Comment: @Larnu - yeah, I think the problem is the PHP Laravel PDO for MSSQL uses `PDO::PARAM_STR` for `floats`, and `PDO::PARAM_INT` for `int`, so that is how I ended up in this situation. I'm just trying to understand the base SQL behavior, and having a separate discussion in PHP land about why the PDO does that at all. p.s. I didnt mention this, because I was trying to keep this question focused on the root sql behavior to understand that part.

Comment: @Larnu - thanks though - I get what you are saying, and I'll see how we can solve it on the PHP side to not do the incorrect conversion in the first place.

Comment: @Laurence `definitely works with MySQL` means it's a vendor specific behavior that you shouldn't expect to work on other databases. Looks like your actual problem is about *Laravel*, not any database. Using `PARAM_STR` as the type for floats is a clear, eye popping bug that eliminates half of the benefits you'd get from using parameters, like avoiding string to number conversion errors. It's so serious one has to wonder whether there's some misconfiguration

Comment: @Laurence as for keeping things focused, this had the opposite result. This situation is actually known as [The XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). You have a problem X (bad parameter mapping) and assume Y is the reason/solution (database server bug), so you ask about Y, not the actual problem, X. Post a different question asking how to fix the mapping instead

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos - "Using PARAM_STR as the type for floats is a clear, eye popping bug" - there is no PARAM_FLOAT. In fact - Microsoft themselves recommend using PARAM_STR for floats: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/php/pdostatement-bindvalue?view=sql-server-2017

Comment: @Laurence no they most definitely don't. It could be a problem with PHP, PDO or Laravel, but SQL Server handles numeric parameters just fine

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos - "It is recommended to use strings as inputs when binding values to a decimal or numeric column to ensure precision and accuracy as PHP has limited precision for floating point numbers" - its on the link I gave. There example uses `PARAM_STR` for this scenario?

Comment: @Laurence then that's a PHP bug. SQL Server handles numeric parameters just fine. ODBC, OLEDB, ADO.NET drivers support numeric parameters, in fact they allow specifying the scale and precision too. The problem here seems to be that PHP doesn't have double or decimal types like other languages.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos - yeah, it's a limitation of the PHP PDO. Thanks for your assistance and Larnu as well, you have both been very helpful and provided me with very useful info so I can now try to come up with a work around within PHP. Thanks.

Comment: @Laurence  In any case, if you intend to use strings, use them consistently. And if you intend to store integers, clean up the data *before* inserting them. What kind of rounding do you want with those integers? Up, down, to even? SQL Server and MySQL behave differently, and casting `33.9` to integer will return 34 in one case, 33 in the other